# Describe the ‘intervals’ $[a, b]$ and $(a, b)$, in the case where $a = b.$

Tags: elementary-set-theory, inequality, real-numbers

This is a question from my textbook, however there are no solutions,

would $[a,b] = a$ and $(a,b) = \text{undefined}$? I'm not sure if $(a,b)$ is right.

Comment: What would be the *definition* of $[a,b]$, and $(a,b)$ when $a<b$? what happens when you let $b=a$ i that?

Comment: Welcome to Mathematics Stack Exchange! A quick [tour](https://math.stackexchange.com/tour) will enhance your experience. Here are helpful tips to [write a good question](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question/9960#9960) and [write a good answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer). For typesetting, please use [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just write it as follows: 
$$ [a,a]=\{x\in \mathbb{R}: a\le x\le a\}=\{a\}.$$
$$ (a,a)=\{x\in \mathbb{R}: a<x<a\}=\varnothing.$$